# python 2.7 / exec / what is wrong?

Tags: python, redirect, exec, stdio, stringio

I have this code which runs fine in Python 2.5 but not in 2.7:

```
import sys
import traceback
try:
    from io import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO

def CaptureExec(stmt):
    oldio = (sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr)
    sio = StringIO()
    sys.stdout = sys.stderr = sio
    try:
        exec(stmt, globals(), globals())
        out = sio.getvalue()
    except Exception, e:
        out = str(e) + "\n" + traceback.format_exc()
    sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = oldio
    return out

print "%s" % CaptureExec("""
import random
print "hello world"
""")
```

And I get:

```
string argument expected, got 'str'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\3.py", line 13, in CaptureExec
    exec(stmt, globals(), globals())
  File "", line 3, in 
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'str'
```

Comment: Minor comments: Pythonic style is to use TitleCase for classes only, it should be `captureExec` or `capture_exec`. Also, you should specifically catch `ImportError` in the `try...except` block.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`io.StringIO` is confusing in Python 2.7 because it's backported from the 3.x bytes/string world.  This code gets the same error as yours:

```
from io import StringIO
sio = StringIO()
sio.write("Hello\n")
```

causes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so2.py", line 3, in <module>
    sio.write("Hello\n")
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'str'
```

If you are only using Python 2.x, then skip the `io` module altogether, and stick with StringIO.  If you really want to use `io`, change your import to:

```
from io import BytesIO as StringIO
```

Comment: +1 for `BytesIO`. I think a lot of old 2.x code isn't going to be very compatible with 2.7 :/ Seems like 2.7 is going to be more of a stepping stone to 3.x

Answer (score 2):

It's bad news

io.StringIO wants to work with unicode. You might think you can fix it by putting a `u` in front of the string you want to print like this

```
print "%s" % CaptureExec("""
import random
print u"hello world"
""")
```

however `print` is really broken for this as it causes 2 writes to the StringIO. The first one is `u"hello world"` which is fine, but then it follows with `"\n"`

so instead you need to write something like this

```
print "%s" % CaptureExec("""
import random
sys.stdout.write(u"hello world\n")
""")
```